# Error: cannot find module Discord.js on Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, node-modules, discord.js

I've had a discord bot for a few weeks and everything has been working perfectly. Today I added a command on my git repository and suddenly heroku showed me this error:

> Error: Cannot find module 'discord.js'

I didn't change anything in the main bot code nor in the package.json file. I removed the new command I added and pushed the new changes again, and still got the same error. 
I tried to reinstall discord.js with `npm install discord.js --save` and updated the package.json with the new version. Still nothing.

The bot works if I run it locally, and it also works if I roll back to the last working build on Heroku.

My bot.js code to load the library:

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
```

My package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "redacted",
  "description": "redacted",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "bot.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node bot.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "discord.js": "^11.5.1",
    "request": "2.81.0"
  }
}
```

I don't know what to do because the code is exactly the same as the previous versions. I don't understand why I'm getting this error.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What does "I added a command on my git repository" mean?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the error may lie in your **package.json** file, you are a missing a few key things:

You must include the versions to use for both **node** and **npm** (I'd recommend using the latest):

```
"engines": {
  "node": "12.14.1",
  "npm": "6.13.4"
},
```

Next you need to also define your **git repository** like so:

```
"repository": {
  "type": "git",
  "url": "git+link"
},
```

As well make sure in your **Procfile** you have:

```
worker: npm start
```

In your **requirements.txt** make sure to have:

```
npm install discord.js
```

You can read more on hosting your discord.js bot on Heroku [here.](https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/synicalsyntax/discord.js-heroku)