# Internal error when trying to require discord.js

Tags: discord.js

I am trying to follow the tutorial given by the official discord.js website, however when I try to require `discord.js` in my code, it gives the following error when I run `node index.js`:

```
    /Users/[MY NAME]/Desktop/JimBot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/Client.js:41
    } catch {
            ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:616:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/[MY NAME]/Desktop/JimBot/node_modules/discord.js/src/index.js:8:11)
```

I have Node updated to 12.2.0 as specified by the documentation. My package.json looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "jimbot",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "12.0.0"
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "discord.js": "^12.2.0",
    "eslint": "^7.0.0"
  }
}
```

Thank you for all help.

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: @Pepe_Worm
Yes: 

`const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.once('ready', () => {
 console.log('Ready!');
});

client.login([token]);`

Where I have written [token] is my actual token.

Comment: The code is from here: https://discordjs.guide/creating-your-bot/#creating-the-bot-file

Comment: Is that all your code right now or are there more? Also, did you save your current code?

Comment: That's all there is. I'm following the tutorial word for word. I got it to work on heroku, but it won't work on my (mac) laptop.

Comment: Do you have a try...catch somewhere?

Comment: No, not in my own code. The try/catch statements are in the library.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js'); 
const client = new Discord.Client(); 

client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log('Ready!');
});

client.login([token]);
```

Comment: Error persisted.

Comment: @chokkore Did you save it?

Comment: Yes, I did save it. I might make a vm for this so that nothing else interferes.

Answer (score 0):

I have been trying to solve this issue for 3 days now. I've finally found a solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59796074/9725459

Basically add (or update) your engines in the package.json file like this:

```
"engines": {
    "node": "12.14.1",
    "npm": "6.13.4"
},
```